# iPhone to Mac audio Airplay not working in Monterey

Tags: airplay, monterey

MacOS Monterey introduces Airplay to Mac from iOS devices but the audio Airplay is sometimes not working. However, video airplay works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open activity monitor, search for coreaudiod, then quit the process.